# Choosing the correct engine in java

Tags: java, lwjgl, jogl, jmonkeyengine

I need to make a program similar to a Lego designer (only for DNA parts instead of Lego). There are so many different options to choose from and I'm not sure whats the best one for my needs. 
[JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/), [lwjgl](http://www.lwjgl.org/), [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) and I'm sure there are others.

Can you please recommend the most suitable one for my needs?

[This](http://www.google.co.il/search?hl=en&sugexp=les;&cp=7&gs_id=q&xhr=t&q=lego%20designer&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&biw=1234&bih=905&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=6d1WUJb5NO6k0AXWooHgDA) is how the program should pretty much look at the end. And a picture here:

[image]

I only know a bit of JOGL programming but before i'm getting into it I wanna be sure its the right thing for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest jMonkeyEngine for this. It uses LWJGL under the hood but provides some higher level constructs that will make your life much easier - in particular it implements a scene graph that you can use to build your world / models.

LWJGL could also be a good choice, but it's more low-level (effectively a thin wrapper over OpenGL). So you would need to implement most of the 3D engine parts yourself.

Comment: Thank you  ! After i took a look on what scene graph is , i think you're right :). Any online tutorials you are familiar with , i can learn from ? Or does the documentation is enough?

Comment: There are some quite good tutorials etc. on the jMonkeyEngine Wiki - http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3#tutorials_for_beginners